# Reshaping table into wide format with unique rows

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I am using R to analyze zipcode and council district data in NYC to determine which zip codes are represented by a council district. I have a table with zips and districts that is currently in long format with two columns.

| ZIPCODE | CouncilDistrict |
| --- | --- |
| 11436 | 28 |
| 11213 | 36 |
| 11213 | 41 |
| 11213 | 35 |
| 11212 | 41 |
| 11212 | 37 |
| 11212 | 42 |

But I want the table to be in a wide format. Essentially, since some zip codes can exist in multiple districts, I want each row to represent a unique zipcode and have columns telling me which council district(s) that zipcode is in.

| ZIPCODE | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11436 | 28 | NA | NA |
| 11213 | 36 | 41 | 35 |
| 11212 | 41 | 37 | 42 |

I have tried all of the following functions with no luck:

```
testing7 <- dcast(testing, ZIPCODE ~ CounDist)
testing33 <- reshape(testing, idvar = "ZIPCODE", timevar = "ZIPCODE", direction = "wide")
testing33 <- testing %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  pivot_longer(!rowname, names_to = "ZIPCODE", values_to = "CounDist")%>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "rowname", values_from = "CounDist")
```

The closest I have gotten is a 1 x 558 table with each column representing a zip code and the each cell being a list of each district that zip code is in.

How do I get my table into this wide format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to group by `ZIPCODE`  and add an `id` column before applying `pivot_wider`:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

testing %>%
  group_by(ZIPCODE) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "id", values_from = "CouncilDistrict")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#> # Groups:   ZIPCODE [3]
#>   ZIPCODE   `1`   `2`   `3`
#>     <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1   11436    28    NA    NA
#> 2   11213    36    41    35
#> 3   11212    41    37    42
```

**DATA**

```
testing <- data.frame(
          ZIPCODE = c(11436L, 11213L, 11213L, 11213L, 11212L, 11212L, 11212L),
  CouncilDistrict = c(28L, 36L, 41L, 35L, 41L, 37L, 42L)
)
```